# When grouped, how to sort globally by sum of group's elements?

Tags: r, data.table

Consider a data.table with the following structure:

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("b","a","c"),each=3), y=1:9)
DT
#    x y
# 1: b 1
# 2: b 2
# 3: b 3
# 4: a 4
# 5: a 5
# 6: a 6
# 7: c 7
# 8: c 8
# 9: c 9
```

I want to order decreasing with respect to the sum of the column `y` while grouping by `x`, i.e., I expect:

```
#    x y
# 1: c 7
# 2: c 8
# 3: c 9
# 4: a 4
# 5: a 5
# 6: a 6
# 7: b 1
# 8: b 2
# 9: b 3
```

The only way that I've found is to create a new column with the 'intragroup sum' when grouping, and then ordering using that column:

```
DT[, s:=sum(y), by=x][order(s,decreasing=TRUE), .(x,y)]
#    x y
# 1: c 7
# 2: c 8
# 3: c 9
# 4: a 4
# 5: a 5
# 6: a 6
# 7: b 1
# 8: b 2
# 9: b 3
```

But I guess it has to be a better way. Any idea?

Comment: Hm, I don't think it's a better way, but you can define a table with the aggregated `y`, sort it, then join on it: `DT[ DT[, sum(y), by=x][order(-V1), x], on="x" ]`